# Displaying letters and numbers in a grid while respecting a few (mostly sorting) criteria

Tags: javascript

I am displaying a grid of products (items to sell on my site).

The logics of the grid item display is:

- 10 items maximum per row.
- Rows must consist of either numbers or letters (no mix)
- Items must be in order (whether numbers or letters).
- Letters at the end of the grid.
- When the rows consist of numbers, only numbers within the same "ten" are allowed on the same row. For example if we have the numbers 3,1,2,23,15,11, the code would group these numbers like: [1,2,3], [11, 15], [23].
  (Then in my code I display then items appropriately in my grid, [1,2,3] goes on row 1, [11, 15] on row 2 etc.

Let's say that the array (category.products, in the code) looks like:

```
[{
    style_code: '1'
},{
    style_code: '12'
},{
    style_code: '2'
},{
    style_code: '11'
},{
    style_code: 'D'
},{
    style_code: 'A'
},{
    style_code: 'B'
},{
    style_code: 'CAB'
},{
    style_code: 'CAA'
},{
    style_code: 'F'
},{
    style_code: 'G'
},{
    style_code: 'H'
},{
    style_code: 'I'
},{
    style_code: 'J'
},{
    style_code: 'K'
}]
```

The groups would look like:
[1,2], [11,12], [A, B, CAA, CAB, D, F, G, H, I, J], [K]

The code, right now, groups the numbers correctly.

However when it comes to letters, the code puts them all in the same group -- which is not the desired behaviour, and I need some help correcting the code to make it work as wanted.

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

// Grouping the style codes
function groupBy(ary, keyFunc) {
    var r = {};
    ary.forEach(function (x) {
        var y = keyFunc(x.style_code);
        r[y] = (r[y] || []).concat(x);
    });
    return Object.keys(r).map(function (y) {
        return r[y];
    });
}

category.products.sort(dynamicSort('style_code'));

if (category.products.length > 0) {
    var sortedProductsArray = groupBy(category.products, isNaN);

    if (sortedProductsArray[1]) {
        sortedProductsArray = [].concat(
            groupBy(sortedProductsArray[0], function (x) { return Math.floor(x / 10) }),
            [sortedProductsArray[1].sort()]
        );
    } else {
        sortedProductsArray = groupBy(sortedProductsArray[0], function (x) {
            // if (!isNaN(x)) {
                return Math.floor(x / 10);
            // }
            // return x;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is "K" in a different group (array)? what is the logic for that?  Is that due to it being the next of 10 items? (just want to clarify)

Comment: Yes -- rows can only have 10 items. So since we have 10 items in a group already then K starts another array.

Comment: Great.  It appears that you have an answer that will resolve your issue (I did not deeply test that by Nina but it appears to be decent by adding another properly) - if not, I could prepare an alternative approach, just add a note.

Comment: Thank you! Ended up having a fix before Nina answers. I like Nina's answer though so I'll vote that one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I apply for all elements a new property `group`, which holds the information about the sort order (as string):

```
style_code group comment
---------- ----- ---------------------------------
      1      0   integer part of log10(style_code)
     11      1   integer part of log10(style_code)
      a      l   small letter l for all not numeric strings
```

Then I sort the data with the `group` and `style_code`. The last point is to reassamble the sorted group in pages. so a new page is applyed if it is the first page or the group has changed or the length of the page has reached 10.

If needed, you may delete the property `group` from all elements in `paged` with this code:

```
function deleteGroup(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach(deleteGroup);
    } else {
        delete a.group;
    }
}
paged.forEach(deleteGroup);
```

**Now the working example:**

```js
function getPaged() {
    data.forEach(function (a) {
        a.group = isFinite(a.style_code) ? '' + (Math.log(a.style_code) / Math.log(10) | 0) : 'l';
    });
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.group.localeCompare(b.group) || a.style_code.localeCompare(b.style_code);
    });
    return data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var i = r.length - 1,
            j = ~i && r[i].length - 1;
        if (!~i || r[i][j].group !== a.group || j === 9) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = [
        { style_code: '1' },
        { style_code: '12' },
        { style_code: '2' },
        { style_code: '11' },
        { style_code: 'D' },
        { style_code: 'A' },
        { style_code: 'B' },
        { style_code: 'CAB' },
        { style_code: 'CAA' },
        { style_code: 'F' },
        { style_code: 'G' },
        { style_code: 'H' },
        { style_code: 'I' },
        { style_code: 'J' },
        { style_code: 'K' }
    ],
    paged = getPaged();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(paged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```